# How does the `join` operator work for string concatenation?

Tags: python, concatenation

How can I properly use this operator to concatenate two strings?

```py
string = "Hello"

a = " ".join(string, "World")

print(a)
```

*Output* ~ `TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`

Comment: note, `join` is not an operator, it is a method of string objects

Comment: The point of `str.join` **is not to concatenate two strings**. It is to take an *iterable* of strings, for a example, a `list`, and *join them all together*. If you *just want to concatenate two strings* then **use the concatenation operator**: `string + "world"`. With `join` you would need something like `' '.join([string, "World"])`, however, you would probably just use string formatting for this, `f"{string} World"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to join is basically an iterable, so you just need to put your strings as a list

You can do something like:

```py
" ".join([string," World"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call join on a list of strings.

```
string = "Hello"

a = " ".join([string, "World"])

print(a)
```